# Problems with draw method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, draw

So I am having a problem with a tower defense game I am currently making. I've posted parts of the code below that I am having the error with.

The rundown of it is that I start the game with the mainMenu which has a button to go into the charMenu or exit the game. This screen loads perfectly fine.

Now when I click to go into the charMenu, I am reciving a NullPointerException on the line "charMenu.draw(g)". If I create just one of the menu and remove the code for the other, it works fine for both, but if I try to enable the code for both of them, I get the error and have not a clue from debugging it what it could be.

```
public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable {

public static boolean isMainMenu = true;
public static boolean isCharacterMenu = false;
public static MainMenu mainMenu;
public static CharMenu charMenu;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

if(isMainMenu && !isCharacterMenu){ // Draws the Main Menu
        mainMenu.draw(g);
    }
    if(isCharacterMenu && !isMainMenu){
        charMenu.draw(g);
    }
    if(!isMainMenu && !isCharacterMenu){
        //draws the actual game board.
    }
}

public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if(isMainMenu && !isCharacterMenu){//The Main Menu
            mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        }
        if(isCharacterMenu && !isMainMenu)
            charMenu = new CharMenu();
        if(!isMainMenu && !isCharacterMenu) {
             //runs the game board
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling a method (draw () )  on a null reference ( charMenu )  that's why the NPE is triggered.

declaring them at the beginning should do it.

```
public static MainMenu mainMenu =  new MainMenu();
public static CharMenu charMenu = new CharMenu();
```

**UPDATE**

you should also update your variable `isCharactereMenu` and `isMainMenu` withing the run function - for instance after declaring `charMenu` - set `isCharactereMenu` to true

Comment: What happens then is that both menus are created at the same time and overlay each other rather than be separately created when called upon.

Comment: Oh i was only thinking abt resolving the NPE... let me take another look to the actual logic of your code

Comment: Yeah, it solved the NPE but created a different problem. Basically, what I am trying to do is have 2 different menus that can access each other.

Comment: Ok how about changing the visibility depending on the one you want to have displayed ? http://mindprod.com/jgloss/setvisible.html

Comment: I figured a way to do it with the repaint() method. What was happening was I was only painting once which was causing the error.

Comment: cool, you should update this post question with your correct solution for others that may encounter the same issue :)